# R: my file is too large, so I got "Error in file(code, open = "r") cannot open the connection "

Tags: r

this is my code, I was doing a LDA model:

```
news= fread("227-509.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,encoding = 'UTF-8') 
news <- data.frame(doc_id=news$id,text=news$text)
jieba_tokenizer = worker(bylines = F,user = "dict.txt",encoding = "UTF-8",stop_word = "stop.txt")
news_tokenizer <- function(t) {
  lapply(t, function(x) {
    if(nchar(x)>1){
      tokens <- segment(x, jieba_tokenizer)
      tokens <- tokens[nchar(tokens)>1]
      return(tokens)
    }
  })
}

tokens <- news %>%
  unnest_tokens(word,text,token=news_tokenizer) %>%
  #filter(!str_detect(word, regex("[0-9a-zA-Z]"))) %>%
  #filter(!word %in% stop_words$word)
  count(doc_id,word) %>%
  rename(count=n)
tokens %>%head(20)
```

++++++++++++

and I got an error:

```
Error in file(code, open = "r") 
此外: Warning messages:
1: In file(code, open = "r") :
  'raw = FALSE' but '//' is not a regular file
2: In file(code, open = "r") :
 Error in file(code, open = "r")
```

++++++++++++++++++

my csv file is so large (about 800,000 rows) I think it is the main reseaon that I got this problem.
How to fix it in R? Thank you very much.

Comment: Looks from the error message that there’s a problem with the file path.

Comment: No, the size of the file isn't the issue at all. 800 k rows isn't even large.

Comment: Also, can you indicate which line of code throws the error? I'm having trouble seeing which function there would open a `file` connection. I believe `fread` shouldn't do so (unless you set `yaml = TRUE` which you didn't).